# Jquery Popup Overlay flicks on page load?

Tags: jquery

I m using `JQuery Popup Overlay` in an application. It works good but have an issue. On page load it flicks and disappear after that. I have done my best but couldn't figure it out. Can you please help.

Here is my Code:

MarkUp of Model:

```
     <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="standardModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
    id="confirm_password">
        <div id="" class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="TSPopUpHeader">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:ClosePasswordPopUp();"
                    class="close" type="button">
                    ×</button>
                <h4 id="TSPasswordPopUpHeading" class="modal-title">
                    Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <p class="PasswordPopUpBody" id="TSPasswordPopUpBody">
                    Please enter password to confirm&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <%=Html.Password("password", null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:50%;", @id = "password" })%>
                    <span id="error_message" class="PasswordErrorMessageDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="TSPopUpFooter">
                <input type="button" id="password_ok" value="Ok" class="btn btn-green" />
                &nbsp;
                <input type="button" id="password_cancel" onclick="javascript:ClosePasswordPopUp();"
                    class="btn btn-green" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java Script Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#confirm_password").popup(
        {
            focuselement: "#password"
        });

        $("#confirm_password").popup('hide');
}
```

Comment: what version of jquery library is popup() from?

Comment: @Siva it is jQuery v1.7.2, any help please

Comment: I used jQueryUI dialog box in following http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/BC5sz/  I am not able to find popup method in jquery for some reason.

Comment: Did you write your own popup plugin? If so can you please add the method/plugin as well?

Answer (score 1):

As you've said you are using "JQuery Popup Overlay" and with your markup style I assume you are using [Vast-engineering](http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/) one.

The popup flicks because it is clearly visible in the code you provided for document ready is to initiate and to hide after that.

I suggest you go through the documentation of the plugin first before implementation as though you have stated `It works good` but I highly doubt that looking at your markups which is not inline to the requirement in some places.

Well, to the point of your problem you should not initiate it with a hide call, instead call it with its `autoopen` option.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#confirm_password").popup(
        {
            autoopen: true,
            focuselement: "#password"
        });
}
```

It will be easy to troubleshoot if you provide a demo further.